# jQuery AJAX Access-Control-Allow-Origin with different port

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to do an AJAX request to a different http site on my server running on another port.

When trying to do this I get the following error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mysite.com:14245/url.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://mysite.com:14246' is therefore not allowed access.`

I'm aware of the same origin policy. I've tried adding **crossDomain: true** to the AJAX request. No worky. I know jQuery recognizes the protocol, domain, and port as a site so I'm not sure what to do here since jQuery insists I'm trying to cross-site forge myself. I've heard something about using CORS but I'm not sure how to make this work. Any ideas?

Comment: The resource `https://mysite.com:14245/url.html` should return a appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header